# Wireless lapel mic (for use with Canon 7D) recommendations

Tags: audio-recording, video, microphone

I am producing a documentary on a very small budget and am looking to purchase a wireless lapel microphone. I am pretty camera savvy but when it comes to microphones I have no clue. So what I'm after is a wireless lapel mic that I can use with my Canon 7D. I'm hoping to spend under AU$400. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one of these... not as nice as a 55B wired, but if you need a wireless mic, this is close to your range.
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/553681-REG/Sony_UWP_V1_3032_UWP_V1_Wireless_Lavalier_Microphone.html

And I would run it to the Zoom, not the camera.

Comment: Yeah cool, thanks mate. I've used one of these before and they do a really good job. Running into the 7D would be a lot easier, although I know the sound card in the camera would reduce the quality of the audio. Would you by any chance be able to recommend another one that preforms well but is a little bit cheaper? I'll leave this a couple of days incase other people want to answer – if not then I'll accept this one. Cheers.

Comment: I had some audio technicas years ago that I loved... turns out it was so long ago, they are well now out of your price range. I've found Samsons in your price range, but my personal opinion is to invest in a better system. I have taken that Sony set up around the world a few times and it is still kicking...

Answer (score 1):

You would probably get better results with an audio recorder just out of frame. Even a great mic run into a 7D won't sound so great. Tascam DR 40 is a great one, and only $200.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have a Zoom H4 at my disposal but am specifically looking for a wireless lapel.